# Suricata does not work inline mode

Tags: security, networking

I have installed Debian 7.10 and Suricata 3.0.1.

Docs helped me the install (here: https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/projects/suricata/wiki/Debian_Installation)

suricata run command:

suricata -D --pidfile /var/run/suricata.pid -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml --af-packet=eth0

then run perfectly, creates log, etc...
but if

suricata -D --pidfile /var/run/suricata.pid -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -q 0

suricata no creates log, does not write /var/log/suricata/*.log files, and nothing happens...

This is a VirtualBox Virtual Machine with 1 NIC.
I have installed 3 vbox machine and problem is really exists on all 3 servers.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using -q implies you're using NFQUEUE which means Suricata gets it's packets from netfilter/iptables. So it's necessary to set up iptables rules with the NFQUEUE keyword.

Simple example for just port 80 traffic:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j NFQUEUE
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j NFQUEUE
```

See https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/projects/suricata/wiki/Setting_up_IPSinline_for_Linux for some additional examples and explanations.

(I guess this would be better as a comment but I need a higher reputation)

Comment: Thanks, but i using this iptables rules. If nginx is available when suricata is running with nfqueue. But nginx unavailable if suricata is not running. Its ok. No problem.

But suricata not logging nothing in nfqueue mode

Comment: If you run 'iptables -vnL' do you see the counters of your NFQUEUE rules being incremented?

Comment: Yes.

Pic: http://upload.adatbazis.eu/uploads/big/00b571fa16c6eca6c72cc4e6bd22468c.png

Comment: You have a similar rule in the OUTPUT chain? Can you start Suricata in the foreground (so without -D) to see if it says anything relevant?

Comment: Ookay, so i now tried wget (outgoing http traffic) and i see the http.log is changed, suricata is logged outgoing traffic. 

But ingoing traffic is not logged anywhere.

Comment: if you want to have Suricata inspect all in and out traffic use iptables rules like: iptables -A OUTPUT -j NFQUEUE & iptables -A INPUT -j NFQUEUE

Answer (score 0):

This also works with NFTABLES, which is another and newer front-end for Netfilter.

Make sure Suricata was built with `--enable-nfqueue`

```
suricata --build-info | grep NFQ
```

Make sure you're NFTABLES and QUEUE ready

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_NF_TABLES
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_NETFILTER_ADVANCED
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_QUEUE
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_NFT_QUEUE
```

Forward traffic even though the daemon might be down or under maintenance by adding `bypass` to the ruleset

```
vi /etc/nftables.conf

chain inline {
        type filter hook forward priority 10;
        iif eth0 oif eth1 queue bypass;
        iif eth1 oif eth0 queue bypass;
}

systemctl reload nftables
```

Using default queue 0

```
/usr/local/bin/suricata --init-errors-fatal -q 0 -D
```

Defaults are fine in `suricata.yaml` but you need to enable dropping within the rules --- if you want to make any use of your inline mode, namely drop packets, you need to tune `suricata-update`

```
cd /etc/suricata/
cp /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/suricata/update/configs/drop.conf .
cp drop.conf drop.conf.dist
vi drop.conf

re:classtype:trojan-activity

suricata-update 
suricatasc -c reload-rules
```

Source: https://pub.nethence.com/security/suricata-inline